# Proving vertex-transitive polytopes can be circumscribed

Tags: polyhedra, polytopes

> "All vertices of a finite n-dimensional isogonal figure exist on an (n-1)-sphere." — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogonal_figure?wprov=sfsi1).

I've been investigating on the subject of regular polytopes recently, and I've found about the subject of Archimedean or vertex-transitive polytopes recently. A characteristic I have seen all of them have in common, and has been commonly cited to be true (but not proven) is the fact that they all seem to be able to be circumscribed in a sphere of a dimension lower (of or the same dimension, considering the interior) than the dimension they are in. That is, every vertex-transitive polygon is cyclic (this turns out to be quite easy to prove), every vertex-transitive polyhedron can be inscribed in a sphere...

I've been trying to prove this but I'm simply stuck. I managed to show that a vertex-transitive polyhedron can be inscribed in a sphere iff any of its vertices and the faces around it can. (The idea is to simply consider to adjacent faces and the two vertices they belong, and assume both can be circumscribed). But afterwards, it seems to be quite hard to make any more statements that can help.

Another thing I considered was using the definition of "vertex-transitive" itself, but I'm not sure how symmetries and so could actually help.

And finally I even thought about Wythoff construction and its generalizations, but even if such an approach worked, the non-Wythoffian figures would have to be considered separately, and since there are an unknown number of them (especially when you don't even require regular faces), this looks like it comes to a dead end.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since isometries are affine linear, they preserve the average $c$ of the vertices. Therefore all the vertices are equidistant from $c$.

Comment: @stewbasic What does $c$ mean here?

Comment: $c=\frac1{|V|}\sum_{v\in V}v$ where $V$ is the set of vertices of the polytope.

Comment: @stewbasic That is, the average of the coordinates of the vertices must be equal to the center? Since I don't know much about isometries in general, could you elaborate on where does that come from?

Comment: I assume by "vertex-transitive polytope" you mean a polytope such that the group of isometries which preserve the polytope acts transitively on the set of vertices $V$. Every isometry (of Euclidean space) is of the form $f(x)=T(x)+x_0$ for some invertible linear transformation $T$ and constant vector $x_0$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem). If $f$ preserves $V$, it follows that $f(c)=c$.

Comment: @stewbasic I had always seen it as a polytope that could be rotated, reflected or translated to move any vertex to the position of another one. I never looked way too deeply into the definition.

Comment: This is why it's useful to say in your question which definitions you are using :). Note that the three types of transformation you describe all preserve averages and distances.

Comment: @stewbasic But how are you defining the average? The thing I don't get is how, for example, translation could preserve the average of the coordinates of the vertices. Unless, of course, you weren't talking about that average.

Comment: Yes, I mean average of coordinates. I mean preserve in the sense that $f(\text{average of }V)=\text{average of }f(V)$. But note that in this case we want transformations which preserve $V$, that is, $f(V)=V$ (this rules out any nontrivial translation). In this case $f(\text{average of }V)=\text{average of }V$.

Comment: @stewbasic So then, what you are saying is that the reason this average, $c$ is preserved, is because $f$ is an affine transformation? Just to be clear.

Comment: Yes, $c$ is preserved because $f$ is an affine transformation which maps $V$ to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact proof might depend on your definition of *vertex-transitive*. I assume you mean *geometrically* vertex-transitive (and not just *combinatorially* vertex-transitive), which means that if your polyhedron is appropriately placed (its center is in the origin), then for any two of its vertices $v,w\in\Bbb R^n$, there is an orthogonal transformation $O\in\mathrm O(n)$ with $Ov=w$.

Now, this means that every vertex has the same distance from the origin:

$$\def\<{\langle}\def\>{\rangle}\|v\|^2=\<v,v\>=\<Ow,Ow\>=\<w,O^T\!Ow\>=\<w,w\>=\|w\|^2.$$

So just choose the $(n-1)$-sphere around the origin of radius $\|v\|$ (for some arbitrary vertex $v$ of your polytope), and we already know that now *all* vertices must lie on this sphere.